# Not able to assign text in UIWebview

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I m using ios5.i m parsing a json object and getting the values in my console.but when i tried to assign the value in webview.i m not getting the values.i have made proper connections in my IBOutlet.but still its not working below is the code and the screen shot

[image: Console]

```
- (id)initWithItem:(NSDictionary *)detaildesc1 Title:(NSString *)title 
  {
if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"ThirdDetailView" bundle:nil]) {
    id1=detaildesc1;
    self.theTitle=title;



    urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://dev-  parkguiden.knutpunkten.se/Api/GetPark?parkid=%@",id1];
    baseURL =[[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]retain];

    jsonData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:baseURL];

        self.title=title;

    NSDictionary *items=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];


    NSLog(@"what is the text:%@",[items objectForKey:@"description"]);
      [self.webview loadHTMLString:[items objectForKey:@"description"] baseURL:nil];    
}

return self;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can first ensure that your webview is loaded into the memory from IBOutlets when you are lading string in it. i.e. viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear have been called for the controller having this webview when you are loading this string to webview.

Comment: yup its getting loaded in viewDidLoad.but the problem that i m facing right now is .i m pushing to a view that contains 4 tabbars where the first tabbar contains the above module.i m able to get the data but the data is not getting loaded in viewDidLoad .

Comment: see. you are using self = [super initWithNibName:], means this class is the controller where - after this call your Outlets will be connected to the variables you have defined in the class. as you are loading the htmlstring in same method, till this time, viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear will not get called. viewDidLoad will only be called when the view is shown to the user by addSubView/presentModalViewController/PushViewController etc. So I strongly believe at this time your webview is connected but not loaded into the memory and hence not able to accept any data.

Comment: i m a noob is der any remedy or solution.i d be so greatful

Comment: you need to move these lines to viewDidAppear/viewDidLoad in the same controller,     jsonData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:baseURL];     NSDictionary *items=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
       [self.webview loadHTMLString:[items objectForKey:@"description"] baseURL:nil];

Comment: the app is getting crashed coz it returns a null value in NSDictionary *id1 ,in viewDidLoad any idea.

Comment: code does not tell details abt detaildesc1. may be you can put some more code to look at..

Comment: detaildesc1 returns the value perfectly that i m assigning in id1.but the viewDidLoad returns me null..i ve posted this as a seperate question. could u help me out.